# BigQuery Simba JDBC connection using access token

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bigquery-java

I'm creating a BigQuery Connection using the access token received from the Auth server. By using this access token I'm able to connect via bigquery java client library. Still, when I use the same access token for connection using the SIMBA driver, I'm unable to connect.

I need help configuring the JDBC driver along with the mentioned parameters.

As per the Simba Google BigQuery JDBC Connector Install and Configuration Guide, the configuration is as per below:-

To configure authentication using an access or refresh token:

- Set the OAuthType property to 2.
- Set the ProjectID property to the name of your BigQuery project.
- Do one or both of the following:
  Set OAuthAccessToken to your access token.
  Or, set OAuthRefreshToken to your refresh token.
- If you use a refresh token, set the
  OAuthClientId property to your client ID and set the
  OAuthClientSecret property to your client secret.

As the doc said use OAuthType as 2, ProjectID=XYZ and OAuthAccessToken OR OAuthRefreshToken with
OAuthClientId and OAuthClientSecret. So, I created my url like

jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/biqquery/v2:443;OAuthType=2;ProjectID=XYZ;OAuthAccessToken=ya...;

But I'm not able to connect with it. It gives me error
[Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver HttpTransport IO error : UserCredentials instance cannot refresh because there is no refresh token..

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers#jdbc_release_1501001 version worked for me.